# Javascript: sum or all numbers not working in for cycle

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

Ok, I tried to sum all the numbers inside `for` cycle in `result[i].quantity` (and yes, it's numbers, not strings) via `+=` or `dataset.quantity = 0 + Number(result[i].quantity);` but console.log returns me: `NaN` or last iteration like `6135` instead of `36726`.

So what am I doing wrong in this simple code?

```
other logic here ], function (err, result) {
        console.log(result); // <<< see №1
        let dataset = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ) {
            dataset.min_abs = Math.min(result[i].min_abs);
            dataset.min_1 = Math.min(result[i].min_1);
            dataset.min_200 = Math.min(result[i].min_200);
            dataset.max_1 = Math.max(result[i].max_1);
            dataset.max_200 = Math.max(result[i].max_200);
            dataset.max_abs = Math.max(result[i].max_abs);
            dataset.quantity += Number(result[i].quantity);
            console.log(result[i].quantity) // <<< №2
        }
        console.log(dataset); // <<< №3
    }
);
```

`result` variable (from #1, it's mongoDB documents):

```
[ { _id: 1520538161000,
    min_abs: 79500,
    min_1: 80000,
    min_200: 118000,
    avg: 108306.51219512195,
    max_1: 120000,
    max_200: 124493,
    max_abs: 130000,
    quantity: 6993 },
  { _id: 1520536841000,
    ...
    quantity: 5993 },
  { _id: 1520532881000,
    ...
    quantity: 5935 },
  { _id: 1520535521000,
    ...
    quantity: 5735 },
  { _id: 1520534201000,
    ...
    max_abs: 130000,
    quantity: 5935 },
  { _id: 1520531561000,
    ...
    quantity: 6135 } ]
```

`console.log(result[i].quantity)` prints me, and it's obviously numbers:

```
6993
5993
5935
5735
5935
6135
```

`dataset` variable:

```
[ min_abs: 79500,
  min_1: 80000,
  min_200: 117999,
  max_1: 120000,
  max_200: 124493,
  max_abs: 130000,
  quantity: NaN //or 6135 but not 36726]
```

I already tried several ways, with .map and .reduce, but I'd like to `sum` all this number at once in current `for` cycle and all this different ways are not working.

I understand why I receive 6135, because it's last iteration in `for` cycle, but why `+=` or any other construction not working here? It's not the first time, when I need to sum every number in array, but it's the first time, when I handles with this one.

Comment: What are those strings there: `quantity: NaN or 6135 but not 36726` - but not, or, Etc?

Comment: guess I miss double slash `//` for comment to explain anyone what I receive in various cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting "quantity" to 0 during the instantiation of dataset.

Comment: btw, but I still have no idea why code like `dataset.quantity = 0 + Number(result[i].quantity)` not working? It's almost the same!

Comment: You're looking to add to the previously set value so you'll need the += operator.
That said, you need to define the value before adding to it during the first loop of the for().

Comment: So it's all about right sequence, am I correct? I can't use `+=` to **nothing** ?

Comment: Correct. You must set a variable before adding to it, text or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing the line: `dataset.quantity += Number(result[i].quantity);`

with this: `dataset.quantity += result[i].quantity ? 0 : Number(result[i].quantity)`

That way you ensure the quantity property on the results array exists before summing.

Comment: `NaN` actually, no matter `Number` or `ParseInt` or anything I paste there

Comment: did you try with the ternary operation? `result[i].quantity ? 0 : Number(result[i].quantity)`

Comment: yea, even before you edit your comment, the result is still `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

```
other logic here ], function (err, result) {
        console.log(result); // <<< see №1
        **let Total= 0;**
        let dataset = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ) {
            dataset.min_abs = Math.min(result[i].min_abs);
           dataset.min_1 = Math.min(result[i].min_1);
            dataset.min_200 = Math.min(result[i].min_200);
            dataset.max_1 = Math.max(result[i].max_1);
            dataset.max_200 = Math.max(result[i].max_200);
            dataset.max_abs = Math.max(result[i].max_abs);
            **Total += Number(result[i].quantity);
            dataset.quantity  = Total;**
            console.log(result[i].quantity) // <<< №2
        }
        console.log(dataset); // <<< №3
    }
);
```

Comment: yea, it's working, but the funny thing is: that I had already tried with another variable `x` instead of `Total` and it not working, even after define it to zero